# Attribute is not saved to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 4.2.1
Ruby 2.1.5
```

I have the following helper method:

```
def parse_potential_followers(params)
  t_id = TestSet.where(:test_name => params[:test_set][:test_name]).pluck(:id)
  screen_names = get_screen_names
  screen_names.each do |s|
    potential_follower = PotentialFollower.new(
        :screen_name => s,
        :test_sets_id => t_id,
        :status => 'new',
        :slug => generate_slug([t_id, s])
    )
    logger.info("Test Set ID: #{t_id}")
    potential_follower.save
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I call this method, the test_sets_id is skipped when data is inserted in the table. The three other attributes are saved fine.

I verified through logger.info that t_id is valid.

All the attributes are defined in the potential_followers table.

I also have all the attributes in the potential_follower_params method in the potential_followers_controller.rb:

```
def potential_follower_params
  params.require(:potential_follower).permit(:screen_name, :test_sets_id, :connections, :status,
    :slug, :created_at, :updated_at)
end
```

What am I forgetting?

## Answer:

t_id is an array (result of ActiveRecord query). If t_id is changed to t_id[0] when used in the hash, it will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `t_id` by

```
t_id = TestSet.where(:test_name => params[:test_set][:test_name]).pluck(:id)
```

which is an array. Probably you should try to get a variable with `integer` type instead of `array`. If your `test_sets_id` is an `integer`, the value in array won't be saved.

Comment: Yes, it was producing a 1 element array

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the data type is different. Maybe you are trying to save string as an integer?